# MongoDB - aggregation with where clause and parsing string column to number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to code up something using an SDK that uses mongodb behind the scenes. The backend has a collection, that stores number values as a string.

Now I want query that collection and check if the value in that string column is greaterThan or lessThan a given value.

Since the column is of type string, I dont know how I can write an aggregation that parses this string value to a number value.

Example

collection {
balance: string
}

My goal, query collection WHERE balance >= someValue

Comment: why is the balance a string?
You can save a lot of trouble if you make it a decimal xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for somehting like this:

```js
model.aggregate([
    {
        '$addFields': {
            'decimalBalance': {
                '$toDecimal': '$balance'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'decimalBalance': {
                '$gte': value
            }
        }
    }
])
```

You can $unset or not $project the extra Field, I don't know how to do it without the extra field.

For reference look here:

[$toDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDecimal/)

[$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/)

Here how the aggregation looks in mongo Compass:
[image]